# sub sample an array with an index array

Tags: perl

Consider having a large array `@data`.
Additionally there is some array `@indexes` that contains indexes to data (consider `$indexes[n] < @data` to be guaranteed for each n).

Is there a simple expression to retrieve the result array

```
my @res;
foreach my $ind (@indexes){
  push(@res, $data[$ind]);
}
```

e.g. (not working):

```
my @res = $data[@indexes];
```

is there something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an array slice.

A slice will return the elements of `@data` in `@indexes` order

```
@res = @data[@indexes]
```

Note the `@` before `data` this tells Perl to return a list where as

```
@res = $data[@indexes]
```

takes the length of `@indexes` as the element of `@data` to return